# Creating a junit test for method an event listener in a JavaFX controler

Tags: java, javafx, junit, event-listener

I'm creating a javafx application. There I have to take inputs from the user. Here I used the instance I take inputs for user name as an example. Here I have created a method that adds a listener to the text field that takes inputs for user name. The relevant method triggers when user click on the text filed.It shows messages about the validity of the input to the user in the nameLabelADD realtime when user inputs data. I want to create a test method to test this function. How can i do it?

```
public class SceneController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    TextField nameFieldADD;
    @FXML
    Label nameLabelADD;

    //more javafx elements

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle){
         // 
    }

    public void addNameValidation(){
        nameFieldADD.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (!newValue.matches("\\D*")) { // Only allow non-digit characters
                nameFieldADD.setText(oldValue);
                nameLabelADD.setText("Only strings are allowed here");
                return;
            }
            else if (newValue.trim().isEmpty()) {
                nameLabelADD.setText("This field is mandatory");
                nameLabelADD.setTextFill(Color.RED);
            }
            else if (newValue.trim().length() == 30) { // Maximum character limit
                nameLabelADD.setText("You have reached maximum character limit");
                nameLabelADD.setTextFill(Color.RED);
            }
            else if (newValue.trim().length() > 30) {
                nameFieldADD.setText(oldValue);
            }
            else {
                boolean nameExists = false;
                for(Driver object:Main.obj){
                    if(Objects.equals(object.getName().toLowerCase(),newValue.trim().toLowerCase())){
                        nameExists = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (nameExists) {
                    nameLabelADD.setText("This name is already taken");
                    nameLabelADD.setTextFill(Color.RED);
                } else {
                    nameLabelADD.setText("Valid");
                    nameLabelADD.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the test method i created for it but it gives me an error saying java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TextField.setText(String)" because "this.controller.nameFieldADD" is null

```
package com.example.programming_cw;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class SceneControllerTest extends Application {
    private SceneController controller;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // Load the FXML file and create the SceneController instance
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Scene.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        controller = loader.getController();

        // Create and show the Scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Test
    public void isNameValid(){
        controller.nameFieldADD.setText("John");
        controller.addNameValidation();
        assertEquals("Valid", controller.nameLabelADD.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: Evaluate a JavaFX-specific test support framework, e.g. [TestFX](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX), to see if you would like to use it to assist in testing your code.  You can create tests without something like TestFX, but then you will need to manage the [JavaFX Platform lifecycle](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html) for your tests yourself, which I don't necessarily recommend attempting.

Comment: The ControlsFX library provides [validation support](https://controlsfx.github.io/javadoc/11.1.0/org.controlsfx.controls/org/controlsfx/validation/package-summary.html) as [explained here](https://controlsfx.github.io/features/decorationvalidation/), it may be worth investigating it rather than creating a custom validation handler.  [MaterialFX](https://github.com/palexdev/MaterialFX) also has a [validator](https://github.com/palexdev/MaterialFX/tree/main/materialfx/src/main/java/io/github/palexdev/materialfx/validation).

Comment: Factor the logic out from the actual UI. You don't need to test whether `TextField.setText(...)` works (that is the responsibility of JavaFX); you only need to test if your logic that generates the result of the validation from the user input is correct. So I would create a `record ValidationResult(boolean valid, String message)` and a method `ValidationResult validateAdd(String text)`. That method can be tested without any UI controls. Your listener can simply invoke `validateAdd(newValue)` and update the UI with the result.

Comment: Both MaterialFX and ControlsFX open source library validators work pretty much as described by James_D, so you can review, reuse or copy their code if you wish.  Unfortunately, neither library provide unit test cases for the validators, otherwise, you could review or copy them as well.